# I tried to update after adding data to the list first, but an error occurs

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let data = try?JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict["records"] as Any, options: [])
                    if let noticeData = try? decoder.decode([NoticeModel].self, from: data!){
                        for noticeAdd in noticeData {
                            self.noticeLists.append(Notice(title: noticeAdd.title, date: noticeAdd.createdAt, description: noticeAdd.content, isOpened: false))
                            self.noticeTableView.beginUpdates()
                            self.noticeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: self.noticeLists.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                            self.noticeTableView.endUpdates()
                        }
                    }
                    self.chkList()
                }
```

I tried to update after adding data but not working
'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

I keep getting this error only. I don't know what is causing this error.
Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe put `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` outside of the loop.  One also assumes you already have a section before you started

Comment: Show your `numberOfSections`  function

Comment: @Paulw11 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return noticeLists.count
    }  
Is there anything I need to fix here?

Comment: You probably want to return 1 here - The way you have it now you have a section per item in your array; You probably want a row per item.  The tableview is getting upset because a section is appearing without you calling `insertSection`.  You should also fix your loop; You can get rid of the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` and create an array of IndexPaths. Outside the loop insert that whole array at once